# Updating Workspace automatically after Sync/Pull branch in PlasticSCM Cloud

Tags: plasticscm

So I'm on branch /main/a

I sync the Cloud to my local repo, and see changes in /main/a. I pull the branch. Now, to get those files to my workspace, I need to change to the Workspace tab, and then press Update Workspace.

How can this be automated so that everytime I pull a new branch I'm on, it updates the workspace to the newest changeset on that branch, without me needing to manually go and Update Workspace myself?

Comment: You could run the pull via script "cm replicate" and the run "cm switchtobranch" to update your workspace to the last content of the branch. But note that you could have pending to commit changes in the workspace. And it's not always a good idea to automatize it.

Comment: Also I guess that for some reason you are using a distributed workflow. Plastic also supports centralized workflow where you don't need to pull the branches.Just point yur workspace to the central server.

Comment: It seems to just have been a case of misunderstanding the usage patterns. In effect, I was doing a specific commit/changeset checkout instead of branch checkout, but did not realize that. Also, the distributed workflow is a lot more robust and preferred over centralized, or at least that's what the consensus seem to be (which I agree with).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here, but apparently the Workspace is automatically updated to reflect the latest changeset in the branch, IF I have selected to change to that branch either from the branch explorer view or branch view. If I have selected a specific changeset, the workspace doesn't update automatically anymore.

This is in hindsight kind of obvious behaviour, but it didn't click until using PlasticSCM for a few weeks.